Logit regression in stata
I am struggling to understand how the function "collinear nonrtolerance" works in a regression model.
logit success effective_premiumOK  ValueofTransactionmil_ln TargetCommonEquitymilOK_ln  Friendly, collinear nonrtolerance

So should it says multicollinearity issues as an output or it is totally useless?
Thank you!
just want to know if this function exists

Note that collinear nonrtolerance are options of this command, and not in Stata terms a function or functions. More importantly, this doesn't seem on-topic to me as you seem to be asking for a detailed explanation of the code and/or and statistical discussion. That is not focused enough for SO, which works best with precise focused programming questions based on reproducible code. You need to study the documentation and the code and experiment with different datasets to see what happens.
